# Get all current joins to a query in yii2 ActiveQuery

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is there a way to get all joined table from a query?

For example:

```
query = Account::find()->joinWith(['gallery'])->joinWith(['articles'])->etc...
```

Is there any integrated method in yii2 that will return the above joined tables (or an event on which I could hook to get them manually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution suggested by @Beowulfenator shows only joins with relations (which added with `joinWith()` method.

To show all joins you need prepare the query like this:

```
$query = Account::find()
    ->join('...', '...')
    ->joinWith(['gallery', 'articles']); // By the way, you can reduce you code like this

$query->prepare();
```

This will transform `yii\db\ActiveQuery` to simple `yii\db\Query` which doesn't have `joinWith` property but has `join` property that shows exactly all joins.

You can `var_dump` and see it:

```
var_dump($query->join);
exit();
```

First element stores type of join, second - table name (note that it can be either string or array depending on used relation), third - `on` condition.

Comment: The prepare method was the thing that i\ve missed. Thank you.

Comment: I had to use it like this: 
```$query->prepare((new \yii\db\QueryBuilder(Yii::$app->db)));
var_dump($query->join);```
Maybe something has been updated since 2015!

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveQuery` class has `joinWith` public property. It's an array that contains information on all joins. It, among other things, contains joined table names.

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#$joinWith-detail).